# Message Integrity Check

Tags: security

I have a question about the message integrity check.

What is the function of 'MIC', and how is it related to the security in BLE?

Thanks in advance!
Benedikt

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42513493/7763210

> CRC and MIC are part of the data packets and checked already on Link
>   Layer level. You do not need to implement extra code in your
>   appliccation to do this checking.
>
> Data packets from a BLE device do not automatically contain a time
>   stamp. Note that many peripheral devices do not even have a clock and
>   thus can't know the current time.
>
> If you want to have a time stamp with your message, you typically have
>   two options:
>
> 1) You log the time on the central device; in this case, the time
>   stamp is the time of the incoming read
>   response/notification/indication. This has the advantage that it is
>   easy to implement, but you lose the information when the data was
>   actually collected, which may be important if there is a relevant time
>   discrepancy between collection and receiving of the data.
>
> 2) You log the time on the peripheral device and send it as additional
>   data together with the original message (for example, adding a few
>   bytes at the end of the message that represent the date and time).
>   This is the recommended approach, but you have to be able to define
>   the messages sent by the peripheral device. If you only have control
>   over the central, this option is not possible.